# Problems loading CSV file in Julia

Tags: julia

I'm trying to use the `Queryverse` to load a `csv` file, like this

```
using Queryverse

df = load("my_file.csv"
        , delim = ";"
        , row_estimate = 215_000
        , type_detect_rows = 2_000) |> 
    DataFrame
```

but I get the following error:

```
MethodError: no method matching UInt8(::String)
```

I'm sorry, I can't share an example of the file.

The error message is not very informative. I'm guessing there might be some problem with the type detection of the rows - that's why I played around with the with the function parameters, but it doesn't seem to work out.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I do not know Queryverse enough to diagnose the exact problems, but I can suggest you to try using CSV.jl for reading CSV files - maybe then the issue will be just resolved? (in particular in CSV.jl you do not have `row_estimate` and `type_detect_rows` kwargs as this is handled automatically by the packages without a hint)

Comment: The error message is saying that it's trying to convert a string to a `UInt8`.  I'd guess you have a column whose first 2000 rows are all UInt8s but later on use other characters and thus are first parsed as a string.

Comment: That is why I suggest using CSV.jl which does not have such issues, as it does automatic type detection by always considering all rows that are read in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is the `delim` parameter that shoud be a `Char` not a `String`.

So this should be:

```
df = load("my_file.csv"
        , delim = ';'
        , row_estimate = 215_000
        , type_detect_rows = 2_000) |> 
    DataFrame
```

The error you got is related to processing the delimiter parameter not the data in your file!

Nevertheless, nornally the recommended option is to use `CSV.jl` for reading csv files rather than `CSVFiles.jl` that is used by `Queryverse.load` function.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was banging my head against the wall trying to understand this error...